# Angular Scope watch change on filter change (v1.4.3)

Tags: angularjs

I got a wired error

I have directive date picker

I have watch listener while the date change

```
 $scope.$watch('model', function (newDate) {
    if (newDate) {
        if ($scope.hideDay) {
            $scope.dateFields.day = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.dateFields.day = new Date(newDate).getUTCDate();
        }

        $scope.dateFields.month = new Date(newDate).getUTCMonth() +1;

        $scope.dateFields.year = new Date(newDate).getUTCFullYear();
    } else {
        if ($scope.hideDay) {
            $scope.dateFields.day = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.dateFields.day = null;
        }
        $scope.dateFields.month = null;
        $scope.dateFields.year = null;
    }
});
```

My weird problem is that I have a search box

```
<input class="free-txt" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Free search" />
```

When I typed in the search box The watch model changed with no reason.

What can be the reason for this bug and how can I fixed it?

Here is the full demo
https://embed.plnkr.co/yGqE33kZNwGz7NaNDOD5/

> Select day
>
> Select Month
>
> Open the Year modal than Write in the free text "78"
>
> Select The year

The bug when Typing in the free text the day and month change to null

[image]
[image]

Comment: With just the info you gave, the error has no reason to occur :) Can we have a bit more of your HTML and maybe the Angular controller in which you have your watcher ? (like the whole form if it is one). No link between `$scope.model` and `$scope.search.name` ? (like other watchers, or shared properties) ?

Comment: are you watching the same model used in your search box?

Comment: full demo https://embed.plnkr.co/yGqE33kZNwGz7NaNDOD5/

Answer (score 0):

by default angular `$watch` watch object by reference

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

```
objectEquality:

Compare for object equality using angular.equals instead of comparing for reference equality.
(default: false)
```

try to add a parametre to `true` for watching object or use watchcollection and give it the variables you need

```
$scope.$watch('model', function (newDate) {
    ...
},true );
```

---

the directive update the `model` only when the date is valid :

```
    $scope.checkDate = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            var date = rsmDateUtils.checkDate($scope.dateFields);
            if (date) {
                // the watch is called what date is valid with a year
                if ($scope.hideDay) {
                    $scope.model = $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM');
                } else {
                    $scope.model = $filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
                }

            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: The day and month change to null when type in the search box and not if the model is valid. If you open the year modal type the search box and not select a year still the day and month change to null.